# Expressing disappointment in a disarmed way

Tags: word-usage, word-request

Regard the following sentence.

> Oh, you can't make it? That's disappointing.

It's clear and to the point but it also expresses a certain portion of negativity of the experience. I'd like to use another word that will lower the negative connotation. It's still supposed to be there but not as the main flavor.

Instead, I'd like to feel the recipient included in my "pain" and not feel as the root cause of my disappointment. Please note that I know how to explain in in a next sentence or two but this question is for a single word or at most an expression.

I'd like to cause the recipients empathy for me feeling dismissed and ignored as I'm disappointed that, despite my efforts to accommodate the other's schedule, they won't attend. They **are indeed** to blame as the main reason **but** I want that to be disregarded (or at least not pointed out by me explicitly) and focus on my (or rather **our** unhappiness).

Comment: I recalled **[it's a pity](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/654/is-there-a-more-modern-way-to-say-its-a-pity)**, but I'm not 100% sure in its tone, being a non-native speaker.

Comment: I agree with @CopperKettle. It is a common usage to represent dismissal.

Comment: @CopperKettle Is it a comment or a reply? If it's the latter, you might want to post it as such.

Comment: A comment, since I'm not sure whether this phrase is spot-on.

Comment: @CopperKettle I see. Although I feel that it certainly complies with the question's intention so I'm disappointed (pun intended) that you don't post it as a reply. Even if it's not accepted as the answer, it's still a productive contribution, in my opinion. In fact, it's a pity you said that.   :)

Comment: @CopperKettle: The phrase is spot on. Post it as the answer.

Comment: They won't attend *what?* A business meeting? A date? The grand opening of your business? Your best friend's wedding? The reading of your father's will? The nature of the event would provide more context with which to provide answers (for example, the formality, frequency, gravity of the event are important). I've closevoted this answer as being unclear and needing more context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it has been said that the phrase is spot-on, here it is:

> Oh, you can't make it? **It's a pity** (or "That's a pity)

Comment: To me, it depends on the gravity of the situation. I would not generally use words such as *pity* and *shame* for everyday events such as a missed appointment (missed dinner, missed movie, or even a missed dinner date). I would employ them for more important or serious events such as missing a wedding, funeral, etc. But the OP hasn't specified the event that was missed. Additionally, using *pity* and *shame* often refer to the other person's fortune, not to the speaker's. *That's too bad* is vague enough to mean anything and could fit the OP's scenario.

Comment: @NES - thank you for the clarification! I felt it could be a bit off the spot.

Comment: I closevoted the question because it is unclear and could stand some more specific context.

Comment: @NES It's supposed to be general and that's why I chose not to provide closer details. The question is about finding a good word for *disappointed* according to the connotations described in the question. You seem to get hung on the part with missing an event or opportunity but that's not the aim of the question, so I understand you're confused. I only want to find a word that complies with the provided intention. I hope this makes it clearer for you. If you can think of different possible suggestions, why not put them in an answer for completeness' sake? We're looking for a generic version.

Comment: @CopperKettle I disagree with NES. While *it's a shame* is a bit too strong, that's not what you suggested - the user add that on his own. And *it's a pity* is definitely usable in everyday's cases, in my opinion, so I'm leaning towards accepting it as the answer. Your reply complies with all the specs in the question, I'd say, so it's **one possible** answer. I was kind of hoping for several different suggestions. Maybe NES will provide a few more.

Comment: I find the requirements set by you to be too constraining for me to offer germane suggestions, and, anyway, it seems your happy with *pity*.

Comment: I must say, however, that a NES would not commonly say either *That's a pity* or *It's a pity* in this general context. The construction with *it's* is almost followed by a *that clause* giving more information (*It's a pity that you couldn't make it*) and *That's a pity* is not something I would say or recommend to a learner to express a softer form of disappointment. Both phrases easily come to express sympathy with your interlocutor's situation.

Comment: @NES Interesting statement in the last sentence. I suspect we're talking about different situations. In the one I'm talking about, it's **I** who's pissed off because of the other person arrogant dismissing the meeting. Still, being civil, I express it as *being disappointed*. Then, I realize that it's still a bit of an accusation and I prefer the interlocutor (awesome word, BTW, thanks!) to rather feel empathy for me, although they actually know that the no-show-guy did so just to spite me.

Answer (score 5):

In expressing your disappointment when hearing such news, a few of the most broadly used expressions are the followings:

> (Oh really?) I am sorry to hear that.
>
> (Oh, really?) That's too bad.

"That's too bad" doesn't necessarily imply the listener's action (that caused your disappointment) is too bad literally. It is a common expression to share your sympathy with him/her.

The [link](http://www.ihbristol.com/useful-english-expressions/example/disappointment1/8) shows some other expressions and their connotations.

Comment: I'm a fan of "that's too bad" since that's what I usually use.

Comment: While being neutral and not accusative towards the recipient, those are not fully acceptable because they're omitting the implication of the speaker's unhappiness, disappointment and negative experience. They imply that **the situation** is regrettable but not that **the speaker** is experiencing anything.